# unknown SSL error -12218 (SSL_ENCRYPTION_FAILURE) while launching upwork application on debian stretch

Tags: ssl, debian, command-line-interface

Recently I've been installing upwork application on my debian system.It has installed fine.But when I try to launch it from cli typing: upwork

a bunch of errors happen.

[1008/213534:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(173)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment for more information on developing with the sandbox on.

[1008/213535:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(200)] Running without renderer sandbox
[1008/213542:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(200)] Running without renderer sandbox
[1008/213542:WARNING:channel.cc(549)] Failed to send message to ack remove remote endpoint (local ID 1, remote ID 1)

[1008/213542:WARNING:channel.cc(549)] Failed to send message to ack remove remote endpoint (local ID 2147483648, remote ID 2)

[1008/213542:ERROR:channel.cc(300)] RawChannel read error (connection broken)
[1008/213542:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(200)] Running without renderer sandbox
[1008/213543:WARNING:channel.cc(549)] Failed to send message to ack remove remote endpoint (local ID 1, remote ID 1)

[1008/213543:WARNING:nss_ssl_util.cc(370)] Unknown SSL error -12218 (SSL_ERROR_ENCRYPTION_FAILURE) mapped to net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
[1008/213600:WARNING:nss_ssl_util.cc(370)] Unknown SSL error -12218 (SSL_ERROR_ENCRYPTION_FAILURE) mapped to net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
[1008/213600:WARNING:nss_ssl_util.cc(370)] Unknown SSL error -12218 (SSL_ERROR_ENCRYPTION_FAILURE) mapped to net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
[1008/214550:WARNING:channel.cc(549)] Failed to send message to ack remove remote endpoint (local ID 1, remote ID 1)
[

How to overcome this errors?

Answer (score 1):

After online searching the decision was found on upwork site forum
[unknown ssl error](https://community.upwork.com/t5/Freelancers/upwork-on-Ubuntu-an-unknow-error-has-occurred/td-p/136117/highlight/true/page/5)

The problem was how to use the 2 versions of libnss3 packet simultaneously.Libnss3 goes as a security related packet so instead of downgrading it on the system you can simply download the old version of libnss3 compatible with upwork app and then dynamically add a path to this old version to the linker when you need to use upwork app, while the system will have the newest one.